# 戻り値が複数の関数を変数へ代入する場合の、コードの書き方を知りたい(実行結果をタプルにしない)です。

Tags: python

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
上記の画像のように、「戻り値が2つある場合の関数」を2種（①と②)コードを書きました。
①と②の関数をそれぞれ変数に代入するコードを書きたい(③と④)のですが、
③の場合のコードの書き方がわかりません。
分かる方がいらっしゃいましたら、お願いいたします。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

> ③の場合のコードの書き方がわかりません。

```py
def test():
    return "abc", 100

A = test
print(*A())
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Comment: 実行できました!勉強不足で申し訳ないですが、Aの前についている*はどのような意味を示していますでしょうか？

Comment: アンパック(unpack)と呼ばれている機能で、リストやタプルを展開します。`print("abc", 100)` と同等です。

Comment: ありがとうございます!   とても助かりました!